# Virtual desktops with multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, productivity, virtual-desktop

Is anyone using virtual desktops combined with multiple monitors? I somehow never got into virtual desktops because my machine at a time wasn't fast enough to switch them seamlessly. Also, I always like to shut down everything I'm not working on, ideally working on one thing only (albeit spanning multiple windows). Too many windows is usually a signal that I need to finish unfinished stuff, organize and refocus. Nowdays I'm using two monitors and I'm wondering if I should try to experiment with virtual desktops again; or are those two redundant?

So...

1. What virtual desktop programs work well with multiple monitors?
2. How do you organize your virtual desktops on multiple monitors?

Answer (score 3):

I use virtual desktops with multiple (2) monitors.

The program I use for Virtual Desktops is ["VirtuaWin"](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/).

I organize my virtual desktops the following way:
Desktop 1: Internet
Desktop 2: Office (writing, powerpoint etc)
Desktop 3: Programming/Development
Desktop 4: Media (audio software etc).
Desktop 5: Processing (when I have a batch script/programm running for a long time).

IMO: The idea of having two monitors is to have more "context" available while  working.  The idea of having several virtual desktops is being able to order programs according to a set of tasks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using windows 7 you can tell the remote desktop to use both monitors like so:

1.. click the start button and then type:

> mstsc.exe /multimon

It will pull up the regular remote desktop session, but when you click on the display a new option will pop up showing "Use all my monitors for the remote session"

Like this:

\
[image]

Found this cool option [here](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/02/how-to-use-dual-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session-on-windows-7/)

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question.

Comment: @sinni800 this is one of those times that I wonder... "What in the world was I thinking?!"

Comment: Hehehe ;-) +1 for that comment