# Virtual Desktop for multiple monitors

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I am currently on windows 10 version 1909 (Build 18363) and I have a setup -

- Main Laptop
- External Monitor

My goal is to have virtual desktops for each screen. (two virtual desktop, two screens) 
As of now, I can share one virtual desktop with extended screen from same desktop but not two different virtual desktops for each screen.

I came across multiple questions but those are extremely old such as [Virtual Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/179934/virtual-desktops-with-multiple-monitors) or they recommend using Dexpot/VirtuaWin which aren't updated or doesn't support this functionality.

Any tweak or non-paid software would help!

Comment: Sadly, the built-in Virtual Desktop feature, does not support what you describe.  What you describe can only be achieved with third-party software.