# Windows Individual Virtual Desktop

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop, productivity, task-view

I am using Windows 10 with the double monitor and I am using multiple virtual desktops.

In the Mac/Macbook you can move each virtual desktop separately by each monitor but with Windows when you use `CTRL + WIN + RIGHT/LEFT` all virtual desktops move together.

Do we have any shortcut or solution for that?

Thanks

Comment: Windows does not support what you describe.  There might be third-party virtual desktops that do support this, but the Windows 10 built-in feature does not.

Comment: I would like to know if someone knows any third-part application

Comment: Relevant: [Virtual desktops with multiple monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/179934/virtual-desktops-with-multiple-monitors?rq=1)

Comment: Questions seeking software recommendations are actually not within scope.